# Reading a .txt file into a 2d arraylist

Tags: java, android, arrays, arraylist, readfile

Im creating a game in android, where the levels are going to be stored in separate .txt files. Each level will be a grid of characters that will represent a different item on the map, but each level will be a varying size, so I want to create a robust piece of code that will read a file, and store each level in a 2d arraylist, no matter what its size is.

My first attempt:

```
private void loadLevel(String filename) {
    mapWidth = 0;
    mapHeight = 0;
    BufferedReader br = null;
    try {
        String line = null;
        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(mContext.getAssets().open(filename)));
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            mapArray.add(getLevelLine(line));
            mapHeight++;
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (br != null)
                br.close();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

private ArrayList<Character> getLevelLine(String line) {
    ArrayList<Character> levelLine = new ArrayList<Character>();
    if (line == null) return levelLine;
    char[] lineArray = line.toCharArray();
    for (char mapPiece : lineArray) {
        levelLine.add(mapPiece);
    }
    mapWidth = lineArray.length;
    return levelLine;
}
```

This is a little inefficient, because the mapWidth is recalculated on each line, and it doesnt work, because the first horizontal line of the text file is read, and stored in the first vertical column on the arraylist, so it copies the text file, but the x and y coordinates are swapped.

Attempt 2:

```
    private void loadLevel(String filename) {
    mapWidth = 0;
    mapHeight = 0;
    BufferedReader br = null;
    try {
        String line = null;
        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(mContext.getAssets().open(filename)));
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            mapArray.add(new ArrayList<Character>());
            char lineArray[] = line.toCharArray();
            for (char mapPiece : lineArray) {
                mapArray.get(mapHeight).add(mapPiece);
            }
            mapHeight++;
            mapWidth = lineArray.length;
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (br != null)
                br.close();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

This calculates the mapWidth in the same way, so still seems a little inefficient. The hope was that by adding an empty entry into the arraylist, I could loop through the ith element of each of them. This second attempt also doesnt increase the mapHeight correctly, because on the last itteration, the mapHeight will be increased, and then the while loop will not be executed again, but for some reason even if I subtract 1 from mapHeight after the while loop, I get an index out of bounds error.
More importantly, by manually setting the mapWidth and mapHeight, my second attempt still seems to swap the x and y coordinates when storing it into the arraylist.

Is there anything obvious I am missing? It seems there should be a relatively simple way of doing this, without requiring a pre-read of the text file, and avoiding using a normal char array.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Can you post an example of the input file, and an example of what the desired result is? The code you shared explains what you've tried to do, but I'm still not understanding very well how it differs from what you would like it to do.

Comment: Yeah, that would be great...

Comment: Is you map always rectangular e.g. all the lines in your text file have the same length? When it comes to x/y-axis being changed I would recommend wrapping the map in a class with a getter for the map cells, that why you can change the orientation of your map without altering your code anywhere else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm actually can't get why is you first example you have switched rows and columns.
And you didn't said by what you are measuring your performance. I mean what is more important to you - speed or memory consumption?

Anyway I writed a sample input.txt file

a b c d e

f g h i g k

l m n o p q r

s t

u v

w

```
public class ReadTxtArray {
private final static String filePath = "/home/michael/input.txt";
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try (Scanner s = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath)))) {
        List<List<Character>> rows = new ArrayList<List<Character>>();
        while(s.hasNextLine()) {
            rows.add(createRow(s.nextLine()));
        }
        System.out.println(rows);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private static List<Character> createRow(String line) {
    char[] c = line.toCharArray();
    List<Character> chars = Arrays.asList(ArrayUtils.toObject(c));
    return chars;
}
```

}

[[a, b, c, d, e], [f, g, h, i, g, k], [l, m, n, o, p, q, r,  ], [s, t], [u, v], [w]]

Here is the output. Is that what you wanted?

I'm using try with resources block, in case you're unfamiliar with java 7 features. It's a shame, that it's still not available on android. Real shame...